# Can Amazon Lex chatbot generate images as output?

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

Like for example, I want to create a chatbot that provide the map images for location of library in my city. If a user requested for it,can Amazon Lex chatbot generate graphics or image of the map in this case as output for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just images, take a look at [`GenericAttachment`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_GenericAttachment.html).

If it's more complex, then you will have to create custom response payloads which you then process in your frontend application in a way that is bespoke to your application.