# Is there any way for Amazon lex to print/render image on a php website? (webhost000)

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

Im using amazon lambda for the backend for the chatbot and I have no idea how to let the chatbot generate the image from my website. I read about custom payload but the documentation is very sparse and lack in information. I tried to send it with html tags in the content and in json format but both did not work. Dialogflow for example has very straightforward documentation in generating the image but somehow amazon lex makes it hard for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried in code? Are you using Lex V2 or the older one? It needs to be JSON and the request syntax is in the documentation, but Lex can definitely be a bit frustrating to debug. Two things that have helped me when using a lambda is using a tool to watch the cloudwatch logs, and also using the lex test chat in the console. If you provide an example I might be able to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69633494/8880593

Perhaps consider storing the images in an S3 bucket then returning the image link using the `ResponseCard` or `GenericAttachment` feature.

You could secure the image through the use of presigned URL's. Storage capacity on S3 can be managed through the implementation of a lifecycle policy to automatically delete these images after a specified period of time.

[S3 - Sharing an object with a presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

[S3 - Expiring Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html)